# Python requests: Creating an account returns whole html of the website

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program that checks for username availability every fifteen minutes for [the ea website](https://www.ea.com/nl-nl/register). If a username is available I want it to create an account with that username. The current code just prints the whole HTML of the website, most likely as the post request is not working. I'm also not getting any confirmation email that says that the login has been successful.

The expected output would be the HTML of the page that says 'successful or something like that to know that the post request was completed and an account has been created.

My current code:

```
    name = input('[$] Enter a name to check > ')

    r = requests.get("https://signin.ea.com/p/ajax/user/checkOriginId?requestorId=portal&originId=" + name)     
    if r.json()['message'] == 'origin_id_duplicated':
        print(f"[$] {name} is taken")

    else: 
        print(f"[$] {name} is available")     
        print(f"[$] Attempting to claim {name}")
        start =  time.time()

        url = 'https://accounts.ea.com/connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=ORIGIN_SPA_ID&display=originXWeb/create&locale=en_US&release_type=prod&redirect_uri=https://www.origin.com/views/login.html'

        data = {
        'country': 'NL',
        'dobDay': '15',
        'dobMonth': '5',
        'dobYear': '2003',
        'selectSouthKoreaIdentity': 'on',
        '_readAccept': 'on',
        'readAccept': 'on',
        'email': 'gxzsontop^%^40gmail.com',
        'parentEmail': '',
        'password': 'Password1',
        'originId': 'GxzsOnTop',
        'firstName': '',
        'lastName': '',
        'thirdPartyCaptchaResponse': '2186106da168de865.9672411905^%^7Cr^%^3Deu-west-1^%^7Cmetabgclr^%^3Dtransparent^%^7Cguitextcolor^%^3D^%^2523606060^%^7Cmetaiconclr^%^3D^%^2523606060^%^7Cmeta^%^3D3^%^7Clang^%^3Dnl^%^7Cpk^%^3D73BEC076-3E53-30F5-B1EB-84F494D43DBA^%^7Cat^%^3D40^%^7Csup^%^3D1^%^7Crid^%^3D81^%^7Cht^%^3D1^%^7Cag^%^3D101^%^7Ccdn_url^%^3Dhttps^%^253A^%^252F^%^252Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com^%^252Fcdn^%^252Ffc^%^7Clurl^%^3Dhttps^%^253A^%^252F^%^252Faudio-eu-west-1.arkoselabs.com^%^7Csurl^%^3Dhttps^%^253A^%^252F^%^252Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com',
        'securityQuestion': 'Op welke basisschool heb je gezeten^%^3F',
        'securityAnswer': 'gxzs',
        'friendVisibility': 'FRIENDS',
        '_emailVisibility': 'on',
        '_contactMe': 'on',
        'cid': '5RpmNWV7ObvGP8gO6M7xqOEWDXGAEF1f',
        '_eventId': 'submit',
        'pinEventMessage.step': '3',
        'pinEventMessage.prevStep': 'originX^%^2Freg-basic-info-panel',
        'pinEventMessage.curStep': 'originX^%^2Freg-sqa-privacy-panel',
        'pinEventMessage.pageViewEventMessage.prevPageTimeStamp': '1627838999908',
        'pinEventMessage.pageViewEventMessage.prevPageDuration': '38'
        }

        ses = requests.Session()
        response = ses.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)
        req = ses.get(url)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Gibbo\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Velox x01>python veloxclaim2.py
[$] Enter a name to check > ktgjqwm
[$] ktgjqwm is available
[$] Attempting to claim ktgjqwm
Resp. Status 200
Tokenized url > https://signin.ea.com/p/originX/create?execution=e1175372685s1&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fdisplay%3DoriginXWeb%252Fcreate%26response_type%3Dcode%26release_type%3Dprod%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.origin.com%252Fviews%252Flogin.html%26locale%3Den_US%26client_id%3DORIGIN_SPA_ID
Response text > The whole HTML of the website
[$] Time passed > 1.294675588607788
```

[The full response (data, headers, params, cookies)](https://pastebin.com/jg6r5tLi)

Comment: First things, I didn't understand your question and second what is your expected output?

Comment: @Xitiz I tried to make the question more clear. But the main problem with the current code is that the post request doesn't work.